# How do I eliminate multiple Records for single set of group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to retrieve DQ.QID for the group G.Code,C.Code,DQ.PREFIX,DQ.DID,RPTH.RNUM. 
Here I get multiple DQ.QID for the same group.

sample query

```
SELECT DQ.QID,G.Code,C.Code,DQ.PREFIX,DQ.DID,RPTH.RNUM
FROM DQ 
     INNER JOIN RP on RP.RID=DQ.RID 
     INNER JOIN RPTH on RPTH.RPID=RP.RPID 
     INNER JOIN DPM on DQ.DID=DPM.DID 
     INNER JOIN CPPS on CPPS.CID=DPM.CID 
     INNER JOIN D on D.DID=CPPS.DID 
     INNER JOIN C on D.CID=C.CID 
     INNER JOIN G on C.GID=G.GID 
 WHERE DQ.DID=4
```

How  can I write a query?

Comment: Please expand your explanation as it's unclear what you're asking here with what you've provided. Suggestions would be to include some relevant schema details (not all), along with the relevant relationships and some sample data. From this information, illustrate what your output currently looks like and what you want it to look like and you're much more likely to get a reasonable answer that doesn't involve some degree of guess work. Most clear questions in these tags will get answered in a number of minutes, so it's worth going the extra mile.

Comment: Are you after [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)??

Answer (score 1):

Its really hard to work out what you are asking for

Either you need to look at GROUP BY; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx
or make your set DISTINCT;

```
SELECT DISTINCT DQ.QID,G.Code,C.Code,DQ.PREFIX,DQ.DID,RPTH.RNUM
FROM DQ 
     INNER JOIN RP on RP.RID=DQ.RID 
     INNER JOIN RPTH on RPTH.RPID=RP.RPID 
     INNER JOIN DPM on DQ.DID=DPM.DID 
     INNER JOIN CPPS on CPPS.CID=DPM.CID 
     INNER JOIN D on D.DID=CPPS.DID 
     INNER JOIN C on D.CID=C.CID 
     INNER JOIN G on C.GID=G.GID 
 WHERE DQ.DID=4
```

can you clarify more on what you are after - perhaps provide an example of what you want the output to be?

Comment: For the group G.Code,C.Code,DQ.PREFIX,DQ.DID,RPTH.RNUM  i need multiple  DQ.QID, in  a single row.